# ASP.NET Core : integration testing with different configurations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am currently running my app and then running integration tests in another instance of Visual Studio.

I have these configurations: debug, release, test1, test2

My app runs on `localhost:7058` if I run the project, and runs on `localhost:4303` if I run it in IIS Express, regardless of debug or release configuration.

I am running integration tests by running my app, and then running tests in another instance of visual studio. I use the corresponding `appsettings.{ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}.json` file e.g. `appsettings.development.json`, `appsettings.debug.json`, `appsettings.release.json` and these files contain the url hosting the app, for the integration tests.

In my case:

1. What URL should I put in the respective files, keeping in mind that project and iis express run on different ports, regardless of debug/release
2. How should I set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` based on the config selected on the dropdown before running my tests (e.g. Debug) so that my test reads that environment variable thus knows which `appsettings.json` file to use?

Comment: ....are you not familiar with `WebApplicationFactory` and how [you _don't_ need to run your webserver (incl. listening to port 4303) in order to run xUnit and MSTests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)?

Comment: @Dai we are implementing this approach too, just because we are adding other configuration like to test docker containers